# Print a block inside a Views header or Views footer using PHP input

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

There seems to be multiple ways of printing a drupal 7 block via php input filter. What is the most efficient way of printing a drupal block in Views header or Views footer attachment of a global text php input filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try this module https://www.drupal.org/project/views_block_area - it allows insert any block into the view's header or footer.
2. Another way using code

   ```
   $blockObject = block_load('module', 'delta');
   $block = _block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($blockObject)));
   $output = drupal_render($block);
   print $output;
   ```

Comment: is it in core now.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 7 :

$block = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', 30);
print render($block['content']);

```
@arg 1 : module name
@arg 2 : hook name like block_view, block_info
@arg 3 : id or delta of the block e.g 30, map-block_1
```

Keep in mind that you can't just copy and paste that code and put in just the block_id number. The module name corresponds to the module's block your are trying to output. In my case my module name was: "dfp" (its an ads related module). And "block_view" is the hook you have to use that manages the blocks for that module. And the delta id # doesnt necessarily have to be a number, in my case it was this: "smt_180x150_2"

Preview of how my views footer looked with custom block output: http://prntscr.com/5qttl8